# Set openCV basic structures to zero in a unique way

Tags: c++, template, opencv

For test cases I need a unique way to set any structure to zero. For openCV I wrote this:

```
  // Fill every basic structure of openCV with zero.
  template < typename Tp >
  void zero( cv::Point_<Tp>& p ) {
    p.x = p.y = 0;
  }
  template < typename Tp >
  void zero( cv::Point3_<Tp>& p ) {
    p.x = p.y = p.z = 0;
  }
  template < typename Tp >
  void zero( cv::Size_<Tp>& s ) {
    s.width = s.height = 0;
  }
  template < typename Tp >
  void zero( cv::Rect_<Tp>& r ) {
    r.x = r.y = r.width = r.height = 0;
  }
  inline void zero( cv::RotatedRect& r ) {
    zero( r.center );
    zero( r.size );
    r.angle = 0;
  }
  inline void zero( cv::TermCriteria& t ) {
    t.type = t.maxCount = 0;
    t.epsilon = 0.0;
  }
  template < typename Tp, int M, int N>
  void zero( cv::Matx<Tp, M, N>& m ) {
    m = 0;
  }
  // Vec<> and Scalar<> are derived from Matx<>
  inline void zero( cv::Range& r ) {
    r.start = r.end = 0;
  }
  inline void zero( cv::Mat& m ) {
    m = 0;
  }
  inline void zero( cv::SparseMat& sm ) {
    sm.clear();
  }
  template < typename Tp >
  void zero( cv::SparseMat_<Tp>& sm ) {
    sm.clear();
  }
```

Setting `cv::Mat` to zero by assigning a new zero filled Mat is reallocating. But looping over would be slow (now done by *= 0). Using `memset( m.data, ... )` is only possible if `m.isContinuous()`. Any idea of being safe and fast? Is it possible to join some derived cases?

The template parameters `_Tp` has been replaced by `Tp` because starting with `_`, followed by uppercase letter is reserved. That is something the openCV authors do violate too (I copied it from the openCV core code).

`Mat`, `Matx` and derived `Vec` and `Scalar` can be set to zero by multiplying with zero. Internal this is a `for()` over all elements but without the realloc of the `zeros()` assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to zero a `Matx`, you can take advantage of its `val` public data member, which is a good old C array. Then you can rely on the standard library algorithm [`std::fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) to set every element of the matrix to `0`; the algorithm generally does static dispatch at compile time to call `std::memset` whenever possible. Using it should allow you to always be safe but also to be safe when possible:

```
template < typename Tp, int M, int N>
void zero( cv::Matx<Tp, M, N>& m ) {
  std::fill(std::begin(m.val), std::end(m.val), 0);
}
```

Since `Matx::val` is a fixed-size C array, [`std::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and `std::end` should work. If you don't use a C++11 standard library, you can implement it as follows instead:

```
template < typename Tp, int M, int N>
void zero( cv::Matx<Tp, M, N>& m ) {
  std::fill(m.val, m.val + M*N, 0);
}
```

For `cv::Mat`, the documentation says that:

> To set all the matrix elements to the particular value after the construction, use the assignment operator `Mat::operator=(const Scalar& value)`.

It means that you can zero the matrix like this (I couldn't find equivalent overloads for `Matx` or `SparseMat`):

```
inline void zero( cv::Mat& m ) {
  m = 0;
}
```

Also, as a side note, most modern compilers just don't care about `inline`, at least they don't take it as a hint for inlining since they already do a great job when it comes to inlining stuff. Nowadays, `inline` is just a way to solve ODR problems, which don't happen with templates. All of your functions are function templates, so you can safely remove `inline`.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting way especially for larger `cv::Matx<>` if it really leads to `memset()` usage. In another forum I found the hint, that most `cv::Mat<>` instances are continues too. So `if ( m.isContinuous()) std::fill( m.data, m.data + m.rows * m.step, 0 ); else m *= 0;` might be a reasonable compromise for `cv::Mat` (`m.data` is `uchar*`).

Comment: @Kellerspeicher You can probably use `std::fill(m.begin(), m.end(), 0);` and it should do the job if iterators are good enough to go from the beginning to the end of a matrix even if it's not conitnuous.

Comment: Would be interesting if linear iterating along a non continuous iterator is faster than `m *= 0`. Assign instead of multiplying should be faster, but I don't think openCV is internally doing something different.

Comment: @Kellerspeicher I updated the answer, you can simply write `m = 0` to set every element of `Mat` to zero.

Comment: Quite simple. Thanks. Having trouble with the assignment operator for `cv::Vec` and others I didn't thought about this for `cv::Mat`.

Comment: @Kellerspeicher Basically just read the doc. To be honest I never ever used OpenCV, I just read the doc.

Comment: The other approach would have been not only inconvenient but wrong. Looking at `Mat::operator=` it is handling the case `0` with one `memset` per plane. The other approach is only setting the first plane to zero.  For `Mat`, `Matx`, `Vec` and `Scalar` the assignment seems to be the best way. Sometimes the easiest things are the best. Thanks